# Is there a way to apply the inequality?

Tags: inequality, quotient-spaces

If i have for example: $b+c \geqslant 4   \ \ \ 
\ c+d \geqslant 4 $
How can I apply the inequality for the quotient $\frac{b+c}{c+d}$?

Comment: All you can say is that the quotient is nonnegative.

Comment: $\frac{b+c}{c+d}>0$ is all you can get. - If $0<y\le 1$, let $c=0$, $b=4$, $d=4/y$. If $y>1$, let $c=0$, $d=4$, $b=dy$.

Comment: @JackyChong Actually, strictly positive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But what if it is any other positive real number instead of 4? Is it correct ?

Comment: @Mathlearner Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that the quotient is positive!

$$\frac{b+c}{c+d}\geq\frac{4}{M}>0 \quad \forall M\geq 4$$

Comment: Is it true for any other positive real number?

Comment: For ex. if in the condition is 1 instead of 4?

Comment: Yes it works also for 1 instead of 4 for both inequalities, and also for any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: To demonstrate this you should consider the function $\frac1x$ and show that it’s positive $\forall x>0$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that the quotient is ≥ 1 for any real positive number instead of 4?

Comment: Tthe quotient is strictly > 0 for any real positive number instead of 4! It can be shown by calculus, take a look here for the function 1/x http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fx+x%3D0..1000